# Rails model generation fails due to foreign key type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-6

I created a model with the following command:

```
rails g model UserCertification user:references certification:references certification_no:string
```

which is referencing to my devise user model `user:references`.

On the db:migrate I receive the following error: 
Caused by:

> ActiveRecord::MismatchedForeignKey: Column `user_id` on table
>   `user_certifications` does not match column `id` on `users`, which has
>   type `bigint(20)`. To resolve this issue, change the type of the
>   `user_id` column on `user_certifications` to be :bigint. (For example
>   `t.bigint :user_id`). Original message: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint

Here is my migration

```
class CreateUserCertifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_certifications do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :certification, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :certification_no

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to set the type to integer with `t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true,type: :integer`

I also deleted the model and redid and checked with previous references, without success. 
Perhaps someone has an idea?

Comment: Have you created users table already?

Comment: Strange. `type: :integer` sets the type to integer though not `bigint`. Can you try just adding the column with `t.bigint :user_id, null: false` and then manually creating adding the fkey constraint with `add_foreign_key :user_certifications, :users`

Comment: According to the [6.0 docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) the default is `:bigint`. Which makes this even more puzzling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting the type in the reference to match the other table:

```
t.references(:user, null: false, type: :bigint)
```

If that doesn't work, try creating the foreign key in user_certifications explicitly:

```
t.bigint :user_id, null: false
t.references(:user)
```

Comment: `t.references` creates both the column and the foreign key constraint. If you want to manually add a foreign key you should use `add_foreign_key :from, :to`. There is no equivalent in [TableDefinition](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references).

Comment: t.references(:user, null: false, type: :bigint) worked for both cases. I'm not sure why this didn't work before - something strange is going on. Thanks David!

Comment: I just ran into this. Did anyone ever figure out why this was happening? You shouldn't have to specify a type if both migrations are generated with Rails 6 since `:bigint` is already the default type for the `:id`, right? Sure it fixes the issue if we do specify a type, but we shouldn't have to, right?

Comment: I just hit this too, a year later. I need to go back and add bigint to my migrations?

Answer (score 5):

If you see this message in Rails 6 (and likely also other versions), the error message may be misleading and have nothing to do with the data type at all.

For instance, given your example, if the table `certifications` does not exist (e.g. becaue it's spelled wrong), you will still get the error message claiming that user_id should be bigint, even if the user reference is perfectly fine.

Systematically comment out some of your references and run db:migrate and db:rollback until you have identified the reference that is actually failing. Then double-check if it is correct.

Comment: I have run into the above issue enough times with Rails and mysql that I documented a way to find out what the underlying error is: https://tomgamon.com/posts/active-record-mismatched-foreign-key/

Answer (score 4):

**Adding more than one reference?**

*To expand on the accepted answer:*

```
t.references(:user, null: false, type: :bigint)
```

...If you are trying to add more than one reference, you may find that it still fails - but the console error will still direct you to the first error.

e.g. in my case I was adding four references

```
t.references(:user, null: false, type: :bigint)
t.references(:blog, null: false, type: :integer)
t.references(:post, null: false, type: :bigint)
t.references(:comment, null: false, type: :bigint)
```

OR

```
t.references :user, null: false, type: :bigint
t.references :blog, null: false, type: :integer
t.references :post, null: false, type: :bigint
t.references :comment, null: false, type: :bigint
```

Changing the first only, the console told me the first (to specify type) did not work, and gave the same error as not specifying type.

Changing all four references succeeded, which can only lead me to conclude that the console error was triggered by the second reference but showed the first reference still to be the rogue, rather than the offending one (the as-yet-unchanged second reference).

So, if you have more than one reference, change them all to match the solution, (rather than expecting the console to tell you that your edited t.references has succeeded and that your second had failed.)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue due to a very confusing [mismatched foreign keys reporting bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42661) in Rails 6,

Basically with MySQL, currently Rails can report this error for the *wrong column in the table*.

There is a [fix in the works](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42691), so should be resolved in the near future.

If you have this issue, you would need to examine all references in your `create_table` statement, and see if any have a potential datatype issue - taking into account the new default for Rails 6 is `bigint`, and but older tables may be using `int`

Comment: I want to mention how happy I am that you referenced this. This exact bug was happening to me- I had a table where the Primary Key was `string` type, made another table with two Foreign Key constraint columns, and Rails was reporting a `ActiveRecord::MismatchedForeignKey` error for the wrong column consistently. Your mention of this Rails bug saved me a lot of debugging time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One would assume that specifying a type is not necessary if both migrations were generated with Rails 6.0 because `:bigint` is already the default type for the `:id` column. In my case specifying the type did not make Rails happy. Adding a second migration that only adds the references did.

```
class AddReferencesToUserCertifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :user_certifications, :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :user_certifications, :certification, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```